# Indexing numpy arrays only if within bounds

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, conditional-statements

I have a 2d numpy array `psi` with shape `(nx,ny)`. I want to create a new array `phi` of the same shape where for each element `phi[i][j]` I need to evaluate an expression containing `psi[i][j]` and neighboring elements `psi[i-1][j]`,`psi[i+1][j]`,`psi[i][j+1]` and `psi[i][j-1]`,except for edge cases where any of these neighbors are not in the bounds of `psi`, treat that element as `0` in the expression.

I can implement this using nested for loops and checking for boundary conditions, but I would like to perform this operation as time efficient as possible. I've tried by assigning

`phi[1:-1,1:-1] = f(psi[1:-1,1:-1], psi[0:-2,1:-1], psi[2:,1:-1], psi[1:-1,0:-2], psi[1:-1,2:])`

but this does not cover edge cases which get messy, so if there were some conditional way to only reference when within bounds else just be `0` it might work. Or, of course, if there is an even more time efficient way that would be better.

Comment: Could you tell us what the expression you want to evaluate is?

Comment: You could pad `psi` with a row of zeros on the top and bottom and a column of zeros on the left and right. Only then you'll have to take that to account in your indexes. For example, `phi[i][j]` will correspond to `psi[i+1][j+1]`

Comment: @AJH numerically taking second order partial derivatives in x and y for a hamiltonian, so something like ```-0.5*( (psi[i-1][j] + psi[i+1][j] - 2*psi[i][j])/dx**2 + (psi[i][j-1] + psi[i][j+1] - 2*psi[i][j])/dy**2)```

Comment: @stelioslogothetis Can't believe I didn't think of that, ill try that now thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem smells like finite differences. Your best bet is to write a (fast, possibly recursive) loop for the inner points, and then loop over the boundary points separately, imposing the desired boundary conditions there. Obviously, the other way around also works: start by assigning boundary points, then loop over inner points.

That said, if you are having issues with speed (probably because your grid is gigantic), you may want to do a few optimizations, as 2d arrays in python are S L O W:

- try reversing the order of looping: in python (NumPy, in case you are using that), 2d arrays are traversed by rows first. You may want to experiment with that at least.
- try allocating your 2d thing as a big 1d chunk where its unique index is `n = i + nx * j`, with `i,j` your original 2d indices. Again, experiment with running the new index n along rows vs columns first.

These two suggestions combined should give you a massive speedup.

Comment: I have definitely heard that about 2d arrays, ill try condensing then, thank you! I'm pretty new to having to optimize for time, and do not entirely understand what you mean with a few other things. How can I create a fast inner point loop? Do you mean fast because I do not have to check for boundary points if I do inner points separately, does checking for those impact time that much? And how does traversal order impact speed? To my understanding referencing an array should always be the same time?

Comment: Turning your 2d array into a 1d will give you the best performance upgrade with respect with what you have. If you still like the 2d notation, you can simply make a "view" to the original 1d `psi` with the function `n(i,j)` I gave you. As for how to optimize your inner loop, that'll depend on which equation you have in hand (Poisson, or other, say.) In my previous comment, "fast" has to do with how fast you traverse the arrays, provided that the operations to assign each element of `psi` are simply enough.

Answer (score 0):

I've realized that using numpy array operations is definitely the way to go to make the code faster. Pairing this with np.pad to add zeros to the edges of a matrix makes this fairly simple.